# Designing while thinking about Materializing ER relations into SQL

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

Here's my question.

After being experienced with OOP and UML, ER modeling seems a bit cloudy...

one of the biggest obstacles im facing when designing ER Models is that i have no clue on what the materialization will look like:

Let me exemplify:

If i draw an Entity "Students", i guess I'll have a table in SQL named "Students" with the students attributes.

But if i connect the Entity "Students" to the Entity "Courses" through a relation "Enrolled", what will the aspect be in SQL?

Im guessing a table for each entity, but how do i express the relation ? Do I for some relations need to create a table just as I need to do for entities? Or the relation is something that is present in both tables "Students" and "Courses" depending on the attributes i pick for each of them?

This seems kind of vague, when comparing to UML. (I know this might seem like a bad practice, worrying about implementation details but i would like to have a better clue, specially on what the relations will turn out in SQL)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many-to-many relations are also stored as tables.  `Enrolled` would be a table with columns such as:

- StudentId
- ClassId

There would probably be other information, such as the date of enrollment, the method, perhaps payment information.

The comparison to object-modeling is tricky.  ER modeling usually starts with the major entities.  Often, a relationship turns into an entity, because other information is available, besides the connection between the entities.